# how do i refresh google maps marker but not my whole page

Tags: javascript, google-maps, refresh

I use the google maps family API. I want to display a car on the map and refresh it every 20 seconds. This is how i load the marker:

```
var image = 'img/auto.png';
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.19919,5.262451);
var bus = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Location of the vehicle',
  zIndex: 99,
  icon: image
});
```

it does load ok but how can i refresh it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a timer which updates the position (and whatever you want to update) of the bus every 20 seconds

```
setInterval(function() {
    //var newLatLng = ...
    bus.setPosition(newLatLng);
}, 20000);
```